# Quanteda Corpus Segment Documentation

Tags: quanteda

I am currently working with the quanteda package and I would like to segment my corpus according to the pattern of having at least two regex space characters in a row. However, I am unsure how the corpus_segment() function really works. I have constructed the following small example to illustrate my questions:

```
test <- "start  middle  end" 
test <- corpus(test)
test
Corpus consisting of 1 document and 0 docvars.
texts(test)
               text1 
"start  middle  end"
```

Now I would like to segment the document according to the pattern of at least two regex space characters:

```
texts(corpus_segment(test, pattern="\\s{2,}", valuetype = "regex"))
 text1.1  text1.2 
"middle"    "end"
```

Now the word in front of the first pattern match has been removed. After having a look at the documentation I saw that remove_pattern equals TRUE by default. However, I do not see why it also removes the word in front of the first pattern match. My initial guess was that it has something to do with the arguement pattern_position and indeed if I set it to "after" the following happens:

```
texts(corpus_segment(test, pattern="\\s{2,}", valuetype = "regex", pattern_position="after"))
text1.1  text1.2 
"start" "middle"
```

So the word after the last pattern is cut out. I figured out that setting remove_pattern to "FALSE" retains all three words and does what I intended it to do:

```
texts(corpus_segment(test, pattern="\\s{2,}", valuetype = "regex",  extract_pattern=FALSE))
 text1.1  text1.2  text1.3 
 "start" "middle"    "end"
```

The documentation of the function states the following:

"extract_pattern: extracts matched patterns from the texts and save in docvars if TRUE"

"pattern_position: either "before" or "after", depending on whether the pattern precedes the text (as with a user-supplied tag, such as ##INTRO in the examples below) or follows the text (as with punctuation delimiters)"

and I do not see how this documentations explains why "start" or "end" are cut out depending on the pattern_position parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question, and I am filing an [issue](https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/1891) to see if this is the behaviour we intended.

Note that `char_segment()` works in the same way.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.0.0

txt <- "start middle end"
corp <- corpus(txt)

corpus_segment(corp, " ", extract_pattern = FALSE)
## Corpus consisting of 3 documents.
## text1.1 :
## "start"
## 
## text1.2 :
## "middle"
## 
## text1.3 :
## "end"
corpus_segment(corp, " ", extract_pattern = TRUE)
## Corpus consisting of 2 documents and 1 docvar.
## text1.1 :
## "middle"
## 
## text1.2 :
## "end"

char_segment(txt, " ", remove_pattern = FALSE)
## [1] "start"  "middle" "end"
char_segment(txt, " ", remove_pattern = TRUE)
## [1] "middle" "end"
```

There are of course other ways to do this, prior to constructing the **quanteda** corpus object from your character vector, such as the following.  (Wrap them in `unlist()` if you want a vector back.)

```r
test <- "start  middle  end"

stringi::stri_split_regex(test, "\\p{Zs}{2}")
## [[1]]
## [1] "start"  "middle" "end"

base::strsplit(test, "\\s{2}")
## [[1]]
## [1] "start"  "middle" "end"
```